# Question about why проезда to поездку?

Tags: перевод, грамматика

Здравствуйте,

I am novice to this forum and to the Russian language. Can you please explain how come the word проезда switches from про to the по- in поездку?

Для *проезда* в метро надо купить карточку то есть билет. Карточка на одну *поездку* стоит пятнадцать рублей.

Большое спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't. **Проезд** and **поездка** are two different nouns.

**Проезд** is masculine, somewhat "officialese", and refers to "riding" as a concept. It's also uncountable (in this meaning; not in its other one where it means "thoroughfare".)

**Поездка** is feminine, stylistically neutral, and means "ride" or "trip". As such, it's countable.

Comment: Большое спасибо